# Fancybox popup once per session

Tags: jquery

I am a very basic person when it comes to jquery and I have a question regarding fancybox on my site.  I have been utilizing fancy box and like it alot but the problem is I would like to show the pop up box once per session.  Been every where on the internet to try and find this piece of code.  I attempted to put something together, however EPIC FAIL. Could anyone take a look at this code and point me in the right direction. I am using a hidden link Inline

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie_name');
    if(check_cookie == null){
     $("#showAuto").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',//added comma
        'onComplete'        : function() {
     $.cookie('the_cookie_name', 'the_cookie_value'); //removed '
        } 
      });
     $("#showAuto").trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Comment: are you using the cookie plugin? in order to use $.cookie you need to use something like, this https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie . Adding that and changing fancy box to an alert worked fine for me (I dont have fancybox but the results should be the same)

Answer (score 0):

What Server Technology are you using? If you are using Microsoft and Asp.Net you could use the Session_Start() event in the Global.asax file.

Good luck!

Comment: I am currently using coldfusion as my server technology.

Comment: Ok so I added the cookie plugin and it work perfectly.  Thank you for the information I greatly appreciate it.